# PDF won't refresh when re-opening only when refreshing

Tags: next.js, caching, cdn

I'm going crazy. I have a client asking to update a PDF where the URL needs to remain the same.

**For context:**

The PDF is hosted at a URL e.g. `https://example.com/files/file.pdf` and that file is served via a Next.js rewrite pointing to a CDN resource.

The CDN resource has a cache expiry of one year (`cache-control` header is `public, max-age=31536000, s-maxage=2592000`). I can solve the problem if I change the rewrite to a redirect. And I don't have any control over the CDN file and headers.

BUT during testing, the PDF will use the new redirect when you refresh the page, but not when you open it via a link. It seems like the browser is caching the PDF somehow...

**My question:**

Is there any way for me to change that rewrite to a redirect without requiring every user to hard refresh the PDF page? Or am I f***ked?